# Can overwriting variable name in Python fill memory?

Tags: python, memory

In Python, if I have a variable name and reset it with an object, could that eventually fill memory?

```
while True:
    a = 'test string'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What happens to memory locations in Python when you overwrite a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23045371/what-happens-to-memory-locations-in-python-when-you-overwrite-a-variable)

Comment: @AnnZen although in this case it seems that (at least in the implementation I'm using) Python will "intern" the string constant `'test string'`, so that it keeps reusing the same object every time - this is evidenced by adding 'print(id(a))' after the assignment.

Answer (score 2):

Python is allocating memory for objects that created when referencing new variables if they not exist.
In your case, the memory allocation will take place once on the first iteration, and then it will keep referencing the same object in each iteration so it will not allocate the full memory that you have.
This loop can run until you will kill the process without warring about memory space.